# How to convert a string from unicode to html entity

Tags: html, string, go, unicode, encode

I'm trying to convert an Arabic string like this:

```
ص
```

to this:

```
&#1589;
```

Is there a way (or package) to do it in Go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That character is not special in HTML, so you can include it as-is in the output, just be sure to set the proper encoding of the document.

Note that to escape special characters in strings, you may use [`html.EscapeString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/#EscapeString). But because `ص` is not special in HTML, that will not change.

If for some reason you do need to escape it, you may simply use the decimal representation of the `rune`:

```
fmt.Println(html.EscapeString("ص"))
fmt.Printf("&#%d;", 'ص')
```

Outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/M9QD-nRuVOH)):

```
ص
&#1589;
```